# Pattern for polymorphic views

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, polymorphism

Imagine I have a abstract "FriendEvent" model which has several different concrete implementations, ie. FriendPosted, FriendCommented, FriendUploadedPhoto etc. They should all be rendered in my view of FriendEvents, but should be visually distinct from each other (e.g. FriendUploadPhoto should include a thumbnail).

What is a good object oriented pattern to achieve this?

I'm interested to learn if there's an alternative to switching on the concrete class of the model in the view code. That somehow feels wrong because it uses conditional logic where I believe it should be possible to rely on polymorphism, but I have a hard time thinking up a better idea. Are there any established patterns to deal with this?

(I obviously don't want to implement the view logic in the model, since that would be mixing the responsibilities, and since I may want to have different views for each model)

To clarify: How to model the different event type in the model layer is not the problem. There are several well known OO solutions. The question concerns the view code which is responsible for presenting the models visually. I imagine I have an EventView class which deals with showing an event (model). The question is: How to implement this class without a switch block that selects a different code path depending on the concrete type of Event is is rendering.

Comment: Sounds like you would just want to use Inheritance.  Have a base class which has all the common properties and then have your concrete implementations inherit from your base class.

Comment: @Evan Obviously I am using inheritance in the model layer to achieve polymorphism. The question concerns the view code.

Comment: Too little of task statement. What are the class' responsibilities and collaborators? In the simplest case, it might be instances of single Event class with a reference to EventType class.

Comment: I imagine you will have some sort of view()/display() method or something to show the current view, which will be an instance of your baseclass that you've used to subclass FriendPosted/FriendCommented,etc. Does this make sense ?

Comment: @George I'm not sure I understand. Do you propose that each type of event knows how to show itself?

Comment: No way! What I mean is you will have a base event class, but either you will have different handlers for the the different types of events or a main event handler for the base class which you can use along with the base class' subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have some [DoubleDispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) concerns going on here.

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to avoid mixing Model and View. Each Event class could have

```
HtmlString getHtmlView() { /* code */ }
```

but then all events have view knowledge and each time we add a new kind of view we add a new getXXXView() method. I agree that this sees unpleasant.

So we could increase the separation of concerns by having all events offer

```
HtmlViewMaker getHtmlMaker {  return new MyKindOfViwer(this); }
```

Now at least we've got the View code out into its own class. Yes we may well need to write special case code for each/many kinds of events, but that's inevitable. Our first problem is where to put that special code - and that we've an answer for.

However we still have a problem: each new kind of View needs a new getXxxMaker method. So we start to look at more complex Factories and the use of Generics and Templates and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I would just use the partial-view concept. The base class is dealt with by the primary view, and that primary view requires a partial view that takes care of the needs of displaying the concrete class.

Comment: How does it know which partial view to require?

Comment: You flip it so that the "concrete view" is the principal view and they all require the "base view".